# JAVA: HTTP POST request - Exception

Tags: java, web-services, http, post

Consider below endpoint

```
https://testapi/test/ap
```

I am trying to POST request using below header parameters

```
Content-Type : "application/json"
key: "<<TESTKEY>>"
```

And trying to below details in body part

```
   {
      "Type": "Y",
      "no": "3185195"
    }
```

I tried this code

```
URL url = new URL("https://testapi/test/ap");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("key", "testkey");
String postJsonData = "{\r\n" + 
        "  \"Type\": \"Y\",\r\n" + 
        "  \"no\": \"3185195\"\r\n" +       
        "}";
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(postJsonData);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

I am getting below exception on (con.getOutputStream()) when I am trying to run this code

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
```

Also when I debug this code I get method as "GET" in HttpURLConnection object even if I set it as POST using setRequestMethod("POST").

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You use HTTPS. Maybe there is a corporate firewall between playing man in the middle and changing the certificate. Can you test your code with plain HTTP?

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the full stack trace.

Comment: I have updated stack trace

Comment: Are you sure this is the full stack trace? No additional "caused by" parts? If you can connect via postman but not with Java, it is most likely there are proxy or HTTPS certificate problems (or both). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Yes..... There was proxy problem while connection to endpoint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a security manager in the API that exposes the url ?
If so: the object connection is waiting :

- a "connect" SocketPermission to the host/port combination of the destination URL or
- a URLPermission that permits this request.

src : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Cordially